# `dotnet pack` on a fresh project fails

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, command-line-interface

I've created a fresh class library (using VS2019). This is the CSProj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Authors>Itai</Authors>
    <Company>Company</Company>
    <Description>Test NuGet Package Creation using CLI</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

All it have is the `Class1.cs` file from the template:

```cs
using System;

namespace PkgTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

but when I run `dotnet pack .\PkgTest.csproj` I get this:

```txt
PS C:\Users\itaib\source\repos\PkgTest\PkgTest> dotnet pack .\PkgTest.csproj
MSBuild version 17.3.0+92e077650 for .NET
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersio
n.targets(317,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\M
SBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import
 declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Roslyn\Microsoft
.CSharp.Core.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\Users\itaib\source\repos\PkgTest\PkgTest\PkgTes
t.csproj]
```

(BTW - Same thing happens when I try running `dotnet build .\PkgTest.csproj`)

When using VS2019 right click menu on the project and selecting "Pack" a package is created (or when I click on "Build" the project gets built), which means I have all the tools required to build and create a package.

I tried investigating the error, looking for the relevant files on disk and importing them, nothing works.

running `dotnet --list-sdks` returns this:

```
3.1.422 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Any idea how to solve this?

### UPDATE

The output of `dotnet build -v diag .\PkgTest.csproj` can be found here: https://pastebin.com/RTtgWbZ1

Comment: what is output of  `dotnet --list-sdks` ?

Comment: `3.1.422 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]`

Comment: will `dotnet build` work ?

Comment: no, same error.

Comment: Its hard to figure, likely something specific to your machine's configuration. Do you have an older version of `msbuild` still in `PATH` ? Try to run `dotnet build -v diag > diag.txt`, open the file and look at value of `RoslynTargetsPath` its likely set to nothing which is smell for older MSbuild. However, from your output it looks latest. `RoslynTargetsPath` value should ideally be `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Roslyn` for you.

Comment: using `dotnet build -bl` will probably give more usable information than `-v diag`. It creates a file named `msbuild.binlog` (but you can specify your own filename), and then you use https://msbuildlog.com to read the binlog file. It's not normal for `dotnet` commands to try to read files from Visual Studio directories, so there's probably some machine state issue, or maybe a Directory.Build.{props|targets} file doing something weird. The binlog (or use `dotnet msbuild -pp pp.txt`) can help you figure out why the VS directory file is trying to be imported.

Comment: @YK1 This is the value I see for `RoslynTargetsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Roslyn` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @YK1 the folder `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Roslyn` does exist, but I don't see how I can set it.

Comment: This is the build log: https://pastebin.com/RTtgWbZ1

Comment: I would say wrong version of dotnet-cli, do you know where it links to? Did you try the 64bit version of `dotnet` in the Program Files folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an environment variable set:

```
MSBUILD_EXE_PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Remove this environment variable, it will resolve your issue. It is causing the `dotnet` command to use the msbuild in the Visual Studio folder instead of its own folder.

Comment: Thanks! It worked and also solved another issue I had where I couldn't open another solution I'm working on in VS2019 in VS2022.